# How to define tooltip for column header of gridcontrol in devexpress wpf

Tags: c#, devexpress-wpf

I try to define tooltip for Column Header of Gridcontrol in devexpress wpf.
But still it is showing Header in tooltip when it is trimm.

```html
<dxg:GridControl ShowBorder="False" CustomColumnDisplayText="Grid_CustomColumnDisplayText">
                        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>                          
                            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Header_Name" FieldName="Header_Name">
                                <dxg:GridColumn.ToolTip>                                  
                                   TooltipContent
                                </dxg:GridColumn.ToolTip>                                
                            </dxg:GridColumn>                          
                        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                       
                        <dxg:GridControl.View>
                            <dxg:TableView ShowFixedTotalSummary="True" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"/>
                        </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```html
                   
<dxg:GridColumn Header="Header_Name" FieldName="Header_Name">
                                <dxg:GridColumn.HeaderToolTip>                                  
                                   TooltipContent
                                </dxg:GridColumn.HeaderToolTip>                                
                            </dxg:GridColumn>
```

as suggested by Harsha Jumde
Instead use this:

```html
                   
<dxg:GridColumn Header="Header_Name" FieldName="Header_Name" HeaderToolTip="ToolTipContent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<dxg:GridControl ShowBorder="False" CustomColumnDisplayText="Grid_CustomColumnDisplayText">
                        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>                          
                            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Header_Name" FieldName="Header_Name">
                                <dxg:GridColumn.HeaderToolTip>                                  
                                   TooltipContent
                                </dxg:GridColumn.HeaderToolTip>                                
                            </dxg:GridColumn>                          
                        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                       
                        <dxg:GridControl.View>
                            <dxg:TableView ShowFixedTotalSummary="True" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"/>
                        </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

Use HeaderToolTip to show tooltip for column header of GridControl